# Fetching and storing data from form fields (email, password) without user clicking a button using Angular, Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am newbie to Angular and Java-script and trying to figure the following problem. I would appreciate any inputs.

- I have 2 fields in our div class. One of them is a form entry (email) and other one is a drop down menu which has some static values of "occupation" where a user can select one from it. Both of them are in the same row.
- I want to repeat this row (for second entry) as soon as the user finishes typing the valid email address in first row/entry. Also I want to store the values of first row in an array that is in the controller.
- I want to do same thing for second entry and so on.
- Once the user hits "OK" at the bottom, I want take an action on the array that has all the above values. I have the action defined and it works for a single entry but I am unable to figure out 2 things:
- How can I store values of each row/entry in an array without user clicking any button but just on the event of completing typing the email address?
- How can I automatically create a new row when user finishes typing the email on previous row? Is ng-repeat a good option?

Any help would be much appreciated. I just want to get started in right direction.

Comment: You can either listen to `change()` event or `.keyup()` event on input fields. Key up would not work for dropdown, but you can apply `.change` event for both input fields.

Comment: The "Hello World" of client side frameworks is a todo list. You are on the right track about `ng-repeat` but best suggestion is study a todo list tutorial or ready made demo for example:  http://todomvc.com/examples/angularjs/#/

Comment: Great! thanks a lot. The demo example seems similar to what I want to do. I am checking out the code right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider, that email addresses can be prefixes of each other - or at least that most of the regular expressions checking for validity of an email address will already allow "a@example.c" and not wait for the complete ".com".

Besides that, from a user perspective I would like it more to at least press enter to commit my inputs.

The best thing to do is probably to create the new line when you start to enter something in the previous one and just let the user decide when to switch to it (by clicking or hitting the tab key). When he or she enters something there you can then submit the data from the current line.

To check if the email address is valid you can use input type email in angular[1].

```
 <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" name="uEmail" required="" />
```

[1]https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms